# How to Modify application.properties file dynamically in spring application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, polling

Currently we have spring applications which are deployed on to Tomcat Servers.We are trying to update application.properties dynamically on the fly, without restarting our server/service. What are our options?
Do we need right any polling service which listens to event changes and update props file?

Comment: Runtime refresh isn't generally supported by most applications written in Spring. What settings specifically are you trying to modify? The usual approach is to have several instance of the application running and to do a rolling restart.

Comment: I am trying modify external api  URLs and client I’d and secrets.But basically we are trying to achieve update any property we mentioned in application.properties.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Spring Config](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html) project. As per the microservice architecture, you can define a different spring profile based on the environment and you will get the capability to reload application properties on the fly without restarting the application using Spring cloud bus events. The same setup can be useful in monolithic architecture as well.

Comment: in addition here is the link with examples https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-config

Comment: Sorry my project is not spring boot project.simple spring web application  project with maven and tomcat.